# The quantity of items after executing a test not matched with expected quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have an user (administrator) already existed in database. I run the cucumber test and create another user. I expected the 2 users after executing a scenario, but got 1. Where is my mistake? May be cucumber does not count an existing entities in db if they are not created via cucumber...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test database is cleared before every test. You have to create the Admin as part of your Cucumber steps, probably with a "Background:" is the best way.

**edit** To log in as an admin, do something like this:

```
Background:
  Given I am an admin
  And I have logged in

  Scenario: Create a user
    Given I go to the new user page
    And I fill in "email" with "test@user.com"
    And I submit the form
    Then there should be 2 users
```

Hopefully you're able to write those step definitions yourself. "Given I am an admin" will just create an admin user, and "I have logged in" will go through the Login page, logging in as the admin.

Comment: If it is cleared, how i can log in using admin account? And when i execute line "Given i have 1 user" before creating another, i've got 1 (true).

Comment: Could this behaviour be a result of interference with fixtures from Test::Unit?

Comment: Thanks. Working now. Can i share steps between scenarios?

Comment: The scenarios should be isolated from each other if you want to test your application properly. I am not sure if there is a way to do it, but if there is, it's not the best practice to do so.

Comment: OK, and it is a possible to invoke a Rake task from cucumber scenario?

Comment: Cucumber is for integration tests, and it's unlikely that a rake task has anything to do with that. Post a separate question if you want.

Comment: I've done this way. I've created admin in background, but i cannot log in.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:
In feature:

```
Feature: "Manage Users"
  Background: I should sign in firstly
    Given I am have an administrator
    When I am on the login_page
    And I fill in "session_login" with "administrator"
    And I fill in "session_password" with "password"
    And I press "Sign In"
    Then I should see "You are logged in"
```

in steps:

```
Given /^I am have an administrator$/ do
  User.create!(:login => 'administrator', :locale => 'en', :password => 'password', :email => 'admin@gmail.com')
  User.find_by_login('administrator').should_not be nil
end
```

And i cannot log in.

Comment: I've found that when i trying to log in, my database contains no users, but i've created it on first step. May be i not correctly configured an environment.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!
I changed database policy from 'transaction' to 'truncation'.
Thread is finished